# IntelliJ Haskell "Correct path to remote debugger was not set."

Tags: debugging, haskell, intellij-idea

In Haskell, I can run my IntelliJ project but I cannot debug it, and apparently assertions only work in debug mode.

Error message:

```
Correct path to remote debugger was not set. See Settings | Haskell Debugger
```

Source: https://github.com/atsky/haskell-idea-plugin/blob/master/plugin/src/org/jetbrains/haskell/debugger/HaskellProgramRunner.kt

See pic:

[image: Haskell Debugger Settings in IntelliJ]

Please help and/or tell me how to implement a fatal assertion function that does not depend on compiler debug mode being turned on (I like to disable/enable assertions pragmatically)